# VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped

Tags: android

My application unexpectedly closed more frequently. In my log I got this message. Team please help me to find the cause of this problem and how can I fix this.

In my Manifest.XML I declared the following.

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Log:

```
10-08 19:22:54.492: E/onCreate(8584): onCreate
10-08 19:22:54.497: I/AndroidRuntime(8584): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
10-08 19:22:54.722: D/dalvikvm(10000): GC_CONCURRENT freed 167K, 6% free 12446K/13191K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 41ms
```

OnCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        Log.e("onCreate", "onCreate");

        if (Modules.idCounty == null || Modules.idCounty.equals("")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler(this));
        setContentView(R.layout.select_my_photo);

        Manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;

        Btn_Gallary = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img_gallary);
        Btn_Camera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img_camera);
        Btn_Delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img_delete);
        Btn_Save = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img_save);

        lbl_optional = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_optional);

        Btn_Gallary.setOnTouchListener(new myListener());
        Btn_Camera.setOnTouchListener(new myListener());
        Btn_Delete.setOnTouchListener(new myListener());
        Btn_Save.setOnTouchListener(new myListener());

        txt_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        txt_slogan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        txt_dre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text3);
        txt_4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text4);

        btn_lenderLicence = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lenderLicence);

        TableLayout TL_select_photo = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TL_Commonlayout1);
        TableLayout TL_property = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TL_Commonlayout2);

        LinearLayout ln_userdetails = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ln_userinfo);

        if (Modules.ClassicPrintout
                || Modules.subProgramname.equals("MyAccount")) {
            ln_userdetails.setVisibility(8);
        }

        myImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImg);
        mypropImg1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img_prop1);
        mypropImg2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img_prop2);
        mypropImg3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img_prop3);

        mypropImg1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        mypropImg1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        mypropImg2.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        mypropImg2.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        mypropImg3.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        mypropImg3.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

Comment: can you post `onCreate` function of activity ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreate` this condition goes true.

```
if (Modules.idCounty == null || Modules.idCounty.equals("")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

And due to `System.exit(0);` `VM exiting` and your application is crashing.